# How do I export Azure AD B2C user names?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In Azure AD B2C under the 'Users' menu, the overview has the following columns:

```
Name
User name
User type
Source
Object ID
```

When exporting users, the user name is not exported.

How do I get the user name exported?

I've tried what is possible from the AD interface and searched for answers. Found this 1 question from 2021 about same issue with no answer, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/373771/azure-ad-b2c-user-export-missing-mail

Comment: I had this issue myself. I had a frustratingly drawn out ticket with Azure support only to be told this is as designed. For AAD the export includes emails, but for B2C they are stored differently. Only way I've found is to enumerate using the Microsoft graph. Be warned that if you have millions of users, this can take a VERY VERY long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: Exporting users from Azure Portal (Azure AD B2C), exports the user details but not the usernames/sign-in names as shown in the Azure AD B2C portal Users blade and its by default.

If you export users from Azure AD B2C portal, it exports only *userPrincipalName, displayName, surname, mail, givenName, objectId, userType, jobTitle, department, accountEnabledusageLocation, streetAddress, state, country, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, city, postalCode, telephoneNumber, mobile authenticationPhoneNumber, authenticationAlternativePhoneNumber, authenticationEmail, alternateEmailAddress, ageGroup, consentProvidedForMinor, legalAgeGroupClassification*  by default.

Hence, you can make use of below **PowerShell script** to get all the details including the User names:

```
Connect-AzureAD 

$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true
$userData = foreach ($user in $users) {
    $UserName = if ($user.SignInNames.Value -contains $null) {
        $user.UserPrincipalName
    } else {
        $user.SignInNames.Value
    }
    $userProperties = [ordered]@{
        userPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        UserName = $UserName
        displayName = $user.DisplayName
        surname = $user.Surname
        mail = $user.Mail
        givenName = $user.GivenName
        objectId = $user.ObjectId
        userType = $user.UserType
        jobTitle = $user.JobTitle
        department = $user.Department
        accountEnabled = $user.AccountEnabled
        usageLocation = $user.UsageLocation
        streetAddress = $user.StreetAddress
        state = $user.State
        country = $user.Country
        physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $user.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
        city = $user.City
        postalCode = $user.PostalCode
        telephoneNumber = $user.TelephoneNumber
        mobile = $user.Mobile
        authenticationPhoneNumber = $user.AuthenticationPhoneNumber
        authenticationAlternativePhoneNumber = $user.AuthenticationAlternativePhoneNumber
        authenticationEmail = $user.AuthenticationEmail
        alternateEmailAddress = $user.AlternateEmailAddress
        ageGroup = $user.AgeGroup
        consentProvidedForMinor = $user.ConsentProvidedForMinor
        legalAgeGroupClassification = $user.LegalAgeGroupClassification
        
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $userProperties
}

$userData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\rukmini\Downloads\AzureADB2CUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

In my portal, Users blade looks like:

[image]

**The exported CSV files now contains both UPN and User name details:**

[image]